# For some iPhones the beacon didenterregion gets only called after screen is turned on

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, ibeacon, beacon

We are using the standard Apple Location SDK and Estimote iBeacons to trigger an Action on the didenterregion call.
For many users it works good but some have the issue that the it´s only triggered after the turn their screen on for example with the rise to wake function or by pressing the home button.
We already asked the users to reset network settings and of course restart the device.

Is anybody experiencing similar issues? Any idea what could help?

Many Thanks
Stephan

Comment: Lots of issues may cause delays in detection, but if you wait 15 minutes, it almost always does detect.  Do you have one of these phones to test with?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I would be skeptical of end-user claims that it doesn't detect ever.  I often find that users are impatient and if they do wait long enough they will get a detection.

Answer (score 0):

bluetooth use power plus is operated by some of the cpu functions which are disabled when you suspend your phone.